# TemplateDoesNotExist at / index.html Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm learning django when create templates so got an error

[this is the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFdWi.png)

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^first_app/',include('first_app.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are new to django and possibly following older tutorials there is a better readable url routing syntax for django versions > 2.0. You would use path() instead of url(). Check out the official documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/2.0/).

Your error occurs because you are trying to set the url routing for your views in your project folder rather than in your app folder. That means that you need to move your index routing to the urls.py file in your app folder.

In your project folder under urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('first_app', include('first_app.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

In your app folder under urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('index', views.index, name='index')
]
```

*Note: your index.html is below .../first_app/index*

Answer (score 1):

For me it's working i am using django 3.2 in ubuntu 18.4

@@ In TEMPLATES SECTION

'DIRS': ["templates"],

@@In static section add 2nd line

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem: `'DIRS': ["templates"],` but how? Previously django was working for my all apps. But it stopped recognizing a template in my new app. This solution fixed my problem but interested in knowing he root cause and how it is fixed.